# Reference to- or reference of an object?

Tags: documentation, grammar

Let's say that some function returns object reference. How one should properly spell:

- this function returns reference **to** an object
- this function returns reference **of** an object

?

Are both forms correct?

Comment: I'd say the latter is a bit stilted, but not ungrammatical. I'd go with "object reference" or "reference to an object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Amadan: "reference to" is more clear than "reference of," even if "reference of" is acceptable grammatically. But I think the most important thing is that you approach this consistently, and don't mix and match different constructions to refer to the same concept or process.